# progress bar using Negative values which progresses from right to left?

Tags: angularjs, html, css, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have a requirement about dynamic progress bar . In my application i'm trying to increase the progression of a bar with positive values now if user enters negative value it should start from zero to left side of the bar.How can this be possible using AngularJS and css3?

Comment: can you please share with us what you tried so far ?

Comment: Will the value determine the increments the progress bar grows in? Or will it determine the width of the progress bar (or asked differently: will it determine the progress in % of the bar)